# How to call a static method of a type parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, static

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
abstract class X {}

class Y extends X {
  static compare(a: Y, b: Y) {
    return a.id - b.id;
  }
}

class Z extends X {
  static compare(a: Z, b: Z) {
    return a.name.localCompare(b.name);
  }
}

function sort<T extends X>(items: T[]) {
  return items.sort(T.compare); //   <-- illegal
}


Y.sort([new Y(), new Y()]);     //  <-- should use Ys compare 
Z.sort([new Z(), new Z()]);     //  <-- should use Zs compare
```

The sort function should utilize the respective compare function of the type used to call it. This doesn't work because T can't be used like that. How can I change the generic function at the end so I can use the static compare function of Y?

(And before anyone comments, please do not suggest solutions how I could simplify this whole thing and avoid the issue altogether. Obviously, the above is an MCVE-esque example to illustrate the problem and not the full code I'm dealing with.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. `T extends X` doesn't mean `T extends Y`, no?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZJ99m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know what that eslint error is so I can't say but I'd assume it's a false positive.  Is eslint knowledge required to answer the question? If not I'll write up my answer. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz your code makes it able to `Z.sort([new Y(), new Z()]);`

Comment: leon, if your `compare`s dont' use `this`(i.e. other statics used via `this`), you may freely `interface Comparator<T> { compare(this: void, a: T, b: T): number; }`, otherwise you should use it as `items.sort((a, b) => this.compare(a, b));`. This is not a false positive.

Comment: @Dimava fair enough, I'd change to [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6V7Rw) version to avoid bivariance and any weird `compare` ... so then @leonheess, does that make the error go away for your eslint config?

Comment: Okay, I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd give your `X` superclass a [`static`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) method that only allows it to operate on instances of the class.  But that would require using a [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), and TypeScript currently doesn't support such types inside `static` methods.  See the longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).  Until and unless that's ever implemented, we'll need to work around it.

One of the common workarounds is to make the method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and give it a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) that represents a similar constraint.  So the static method will only be callable on a class of the right shape.

So let's say that we only want to be allowed to call `sort()` on a class constructor which has a `compare` method of the appropriate type.  That type might be

```
interface Comparator<T> {
  compare: (this: void, a: T, b: T) => number;
}
```

meaning that we require the class constructor to be a `Comparator<T>` for some `T`.  (Note the `void` `this` context which says `compare` must be callable without being bound to an object; that can be relaxed if we want, but hopefully that's good enough.)  Then we'd write `sort()` on `X` like this:

```
abstract class X {
  static sort<T extends X>(this: Comparator<T>, items: T[]) {
    return items.sort(this.compare);
  }
}
```

That compiles cleanly; let's test it out:

```
class Y extends X {
  id: number = 0;
  static compare(a: Y, b: Y) {
    return a.id - b.id;
  }
}

class Z extends X {
  name: string = "";
  static compare(a: Z, b: Z) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  }
}

Y.sort([new Y(), new Y()]); // okay
Z.sort([new Z(), new Z()]); // okay
Z.sort([new Y(), new Z()]); // error
// ---> ~~~~~~~ Y is not Z
X.sort([new Y(), new Z()]); // error
// <-- compare is missing from X
```

Looks good.  Your desired calls are supported, and undesirable calls are rejected.  You're only allowed to call `Z.sort()` on an array of `Z` instances, and you're not allowed to call `X.sort()` directly at all because `X` is not a `Comparator` at all.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOU5jpQA8AKgHzIDeAUMsglrlBAFzIAUYAFsAM7sAbumAATADTI47UpIBGMgJTIAvJRABXTHOgBuGgF8aNOHL5h8CMAwA2cPn2QANanWTmCwBO6JgyyCAAPSBBRRydyLl4BNCY8AiIycklgSEwY0gBtAF1lWnp6FjANKBBkVIh0gDo+Xyj+KsYcPAhFfXojIxoEOwdkAE0A4IhQ8Nd6MXZNbWhVZAAGdvcwT28m5ggOaQH5dn68t0KIYtKpKrFkAFpkOXPRJc7jHvtHAC0hkLDnceQQOEw2MsoKAAOZzABE4KWHjAXgYcRYW3Yr12yFeBwKyCKJTKcCqfwBVRs6AQcBsEAwzURtwJrQehmM-RqdUyIAgAHcBhxFJI2Zz+tzcrpkAB6EXIdAAazgAE8aK9mVAwBxWRy0dzeWrXoK2qLxVLZfLFcrVfyNb8tTrhWKAlAoEQaDbLs7KAA-d0e10DcqOEDoayvGhOY0qvlcnkWznaxRCvW2+1QR3i4jO+FUlD8ZCYfh8UHIGD2zDOIA)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID = 0;

abstract class X {
  static sort<X>(items: X[]) : X[]{
    return items.sort(this.compare);
  }

  static compare<X>(a : any, y : any) : number {
    return 0;  // Implement in override class
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  id : number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  static compare(a: Y, b: Y) {
    return a.id - b.id;
  }
}

class Z extends X {
  name = '' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  static compare(a: Z, b: Z) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  }
}

var y = Y.sort([new Y(), new Y(),new Y(), new Y(),new Y(), new Y()]);     //  <-- should use Ys compare 
var z = Z.sort([new Z(), new Z(), new Z(), new Z(), new Z(), new Z()]);     //  <-- should use Zs compare 

console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAkgIhC8EAMBuAsAKEyARgZwBcwQBjAiEgGxDzwgA0IBvTCCQkAgSxPYHswBADz0AfAAouBAKYBbPAC4GAbQC6ASghL6alhjZsw0ggFcwAOwhS5eAHR4BBcQQAWXOyT6yADuGnr0fQgAX0xWdgJOHgovXyMRCRAtCBBzAE8AGgg05NS0zSVzE1kcaUg9AwgjUwtkFDYAegboH0o5aXNyLks+YDKwLgATaQpqWnDQjEnMKho6AE0IaQAPGXNBukYKq0HkopKyhAgAWU4XWwAzSj4BcVPXW2J1r3FNACoIAEYkJADwjm4vE8Pj84hASnmWRwEM020MxjMlhAtiGEAAtBAcCjBoE2JNphhZrQIAAtJarDobBjMcLmECyEaIADkTIgAGoTmdLtdbvdzk9Bi93l8fn8ggDosC4tIwUoSVC5bDwvCakjbHSGbZriQQG0AMKxUFYjX+XEhTAE0CQHKIeb2RziZTmaQAdwg81eWWdbo96gy3vdnogAd9-tdgb9wfDvo09UqTTYQjRGLwLj4JkouxMeBG8zoUr8EEwVogAC8jiT7YJHQGSUHa-Xw3XIw2W03G27m7HKhAExAkym0xmsznSfnDUYi1hCXxzA42lq+ABzcT5QKeOd8BfXFelgJAA)